# Overpricing Bermudan swaption using Shifted LMM

Tags: option-pricing, bermudan

I am trying to model a callable range accrual note linked to the EUR CMS spread, 20Y-10Y, with cap and floor. The note is Bermudan, callable starting year 3, every 3 years till maturity at 30 year. We plan on using shifted LMM for the EUR rate.

We plan to calibrate libor correlations to cms 20-10 spreadoptions 1Y maturity because those are the liquid ones, and vols to vanillas. A colleague told me that we will still overprice the trade.

I don't understand why. I understand that Bermudans in will trade at a discount to europeans but I don't understand why the modeling will generally overprice it. Any help or links to papers or books will be greatly appreciated. Also any links to books and papers that explain how to remedy the issue will also be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

well there are lots of things to get right...

first you need to the non-callable version right, to get that right requires getting the smile right since a callable range accrual is really just a bunch of digitals with timing effects.

these days discounting and forwarding are done with different curves so you'll need to get that right too.

then you'll need to get covariance between the cms rates right.

my paper has some

http://ssrn.com/abstract=1461285

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'overprice'  I assume you mean model price > market price.  In my experience this is true for all reasonable models.  It's due to excessive supply of the Bermudan structure in the market.

Comment: Thanks @dm63. I spokes with a friend who is a FI quant and he told me exactly this, that these are one sided markets. He suggested I read Piterbarg. Would you have anything to add in terms of academic or practitioner literature?